# Can't modify olcAccess values because LDAP has passthrough auth

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap, windows-server-2016

I'm an intern working at a company that uses an OpenLDAP server on Linux in conjunction with Windows server 2016. I'm trying to modify an `olcAccess` value in `olcDatabase={0}config`, to deny/grant users access to certain places. 
OpenLDAP won't let me do this; there's another attribute called `olcSaslRealm` blocking me from editing.

How would I go about this? I have to edit `olcAccess` through OpenLDAP, can't do it through AD.

Comment: What are the current `olcRootDn` and `olcAccess` for `olcDatabase={0}config`?

Comment: This shouldn't really matter; I am logged in through Apache Directory Studio as admin. I have privileges.

Comment: If you had privileges, wouldn't it already be working? `olcSaslRealm` isn't what's preventing you from editing. It's related to GSSAPI/Kerberos. If it were getting in the way, you wouldn't be able to bind.